# robovm 0.0.14 NullPointerException problems

Tags: libgdx, robovm, luaj

I have migrated my libgdx(1.3), maven, robovm project from 0.0.13 to 0.0.14 for supporting IOS 8 devices. I have modified my robovm.xml file according to release notes and can run on IOS 8 device but getting NullPointerException's in several places. Problems I have faced are listed below:

- Sounds, musics and vibration is not working.
- I am getting luaj NullPointerException as follows : (I have tried to link org.luaj.**.* package in robovm.xml but nothing changed)

org.luaj.vm2.LuaError: checkOnSessionEndAchievements:5 vm error: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.luaj.vm2.LuaClosure.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.luaj.vm2.LuaClosure.call(Unknown Source)
    at net.games.mobile.game.core.LuaScriptManager.runFunction(LuaScriptManager.java)
    at net.games.mobile.game.core.achievement.AchievementManager$3.run(AchievementManager.java)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java)

- I was getting NullPointerException on Bus.java "register" method of otto library but fixed it applying a work-around.

I think something is changed related to reflection behaviour on 0.0.14 version, because exceptions are related to reflection as far as I see. By the way, same NullPointerException issues are present on IOS 7.1 devices, but "sound,music,vibration" is working.

How can I fix this NullPointerException problem?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: did these NPEs occur with 0.0.13?

Comment: No, everything is fine with 0.0.13